# Allow Fill-in on SharePoint Person or Group Column

Tags: sharepoint

I am using a Person or Group column in SharePoint to select team assignments for projects.

Sometimes the project doesn't need a particular assignment, and I would like to put "NA" instead of leaving the column blank.

The list is tied my organizations directory, so I can't add an "NA" option to the directory itself.

Is there a way to allow fill-in answers on a Person or Group column in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

By using Powerapps you could set default value to Person & Group column.
This issue is about set a user as a default value in Person & Group column.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/126433/use-current-user-as-default-value-in-a-person-or-g.html

Hope Allen Xu's answer could help you a little.

More information about [Defining default values for complex SharePoint types in forms](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/default-values-for-complex-sharepoint-types/)